# Python multiprocessing: How to shutdown a long running process that is a sequence of actions

Tags: python, events, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, code-cleanup

I want to use multiprocessing to run simultaneously several processes of a series of lengthy actions (e.g. clicking through programs simultaneously using computer vision). I want to implement a stop button in a GUI that would allow me to stop the processes midway - but I'm not sure how I can do something like that.

I know I can use a shutdown event to control the processes if there's a loop - however in my case the target function is not a loop. Here's some code where I basically just did an event check on every line of the target function:

(I deleted a large part of the tkinter code as it's not relevant, the start/stop functions are for their respective buttons in the GUI.)

```
from multiprocessing import Event, Process
from time import sleep

def start_proc(self):
    self.proc_stop_event.clear()
    for i in range(4):
        p = Process(target=long_sequential_tasks, args=(i,self.proc_stop_event))
        p.start()

def stop_proc(self):
    self.proc_stop_event.set()

#a series of lengthy, different and sequential tasks
def long_sequential_tasks(idx, event):
    if not event.is_set(): <---
        print(str(idx))
        sleep(10) 
    else:
        break
    if not event.is_set(): <---
        print(str(idx * 2))
        sleep(10)
    else:
        break
    if not event.is_set(): <---
        print(str(idx * 3))
        sleep(10)
    else:
        break
```

Checking the event status every line is obviously not a solution, but I really don't know what else I can do. In the future I want to add queues and locks to synchronize the parallel processes, and apparently process.terminate can leave them hanging.

So if process.terminate is not an option, how can I interrupt a process that's carrying out a sequence of actions in a clean way? Or I can still terminate the processes but do a clean up on the hanging stuff?

Comment: I think `is_set()` is the appropriate way to handle this. What you're saying is you have a long series of unrelated things to process that you want to be able to arbitrarily stop, but you can't write these into a loop at all?

Comment: Yes that's right. The individual steps have to be accomplished in a particular order though.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *how can I interrupt a process that's carrying out a sequence of actions in a clean way?*

May implement a signaling/messaging metaplane, using nanomsg or ZeroMQ, that will smart-inform the process ( which is checking for presence of such a `<NO-GO>`-message, as an example in due places in between the phases of the pure-[SERIAL] workflow check-points )
and once a `<NO-GO>`-message arrives, the process may perform a graceful-cleanup and smart termination of its own run.

The add-on costs are minimal.

```
def long_sequential_tasks( idx ):
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # local
    # mock-up soft-authentcation proxy
    # for otherwise possible ( whitelisting & key-management & other tools available )
    #
    CONTROL_HASH_ID = "asdfhasrtbnastnve9vaergn9ervgnaeragiagiab - WHATEVER"
    LENofMASK = len( CONTROL_HASH_ID )
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    import zmq
    aCtx = zmq.Context()
    aSUB = aCtx.socket( zmq.SUB )
    aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.SUBSCRIBE, CONTROL_HASH_ID )
    aSUB.setsockopt(    zmq.LINGER, 0 )
    ...
    aSUB.connect( "<protocol>://<address-details>" ) # { ipc:// | tipc:// | norm:// | tcp:// | vmci:// | ...  }

    if (  0 == aSUB.poll( 0, zmq.POLLIN )
       or      aSUB.recv(    zmq.NOBLOCK )[:LENofMASK] != CONTROL_HASH_ID
           ):                    # <--- NO LEGAL EXPLICIT <NO-GO>-MESSAGE HERE
           # continue planned work-step
           ...

    if (  0 == aSUB.poll( 0, zmq.POLLIN )
       or      aSUB.recv(    zmq.NOBLOCK )[:LENofMASK] != CONTROL_HASH_ID
           ):                    # <--- NO LEGAL EXPLICIT <NO-GO>-MESSAGE HERE
           # continue planned work-step
           ...
```

The requested effect is achieved in a clean way.

Tkinter MVC-actor-based GUI and any other smart-"sources" of control-messages can live with this concept and initiate smart-signaling/messaging outside the world of the `tk.mainloop()`-scheduler and easily reach inter-platform integrated computing exo-systems ( using this for more than a decade for a remote GUI for a QuantFX prototyping with AI/ML + trading backend ecosystem ).

---

Another way is to implement the exit-plan via a use of a custom-defined signal-handler. This releaves the need to structure the sequence of steps after/before which the exit-plan is being checked in a rather rigid way. Signal handlers can "interrupt" the flow of computations and may (rather brutally) kill its own process (which needs to add some mitigation measures, if graceful terminations are a must), but represents an option, if loooong running workflow-steps are worth stopping upon some external logic, responsible for the exit-plan flagging a `<NO-GO>`-state.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the OP `event.is_set()` approach?

Comment: This way one is free to integrate inter-process control-layer, independently of any form of a shared object ( better share nothing and set explicit control-loops which may include extra-domain inputs, that have nothing to do with pure python )

Comment: It's true that this way opens up more possibilities particularly in cases where you need to connect to other platforms. However it doesn't avoid the need to have the checks at regular intervals along the code

Comment: But your alternative - to catch and handle the terminate signal from process.terminate if i understand correctly - seems to be the only solution. Could you elaborate more on the part where the sequence before/after exit plan needs to be structured in a rigid way?

Comment: I think in all cases you are going to have to write in checking along the way. Normally you would do something like `while not event.is_set():` and then continue but since each function is separate, your option is to do something like increment an `i` and then send to a function that contains all functions where each step is the next `i` and you return each time to automate the checking, but in any case you have to stop and check all the time, it's just how you want to write that step in that changes.

Comment: @JasonTan StackOverflow encourages users not to creep one question into many other of further extending questions. Feel free to accept the best Answer provided to your Question and may you like so, post a new MCVE-formulated problem as a new Question for all the other questions you may have come to. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Hi, yeah ok I will read into signal handling and ask a question on that if needed. I think you guys are right though without catching the kill signal there's no avoiding having event/socket checks at close to every line, I did think about having a dictionary or list of functions which I can loop around, but it's going to be quite unreadable. Thanks for your help guys.